# Magento 2.3 - Category Page in CMS blank amongst other errors

Tags: checkout, knockoutjs, mini-cart, magento2.3.1

Experiencing some weird behaviour in Magento 2. It's 2.3.1 (recently upgraded from 2.2.4 but it we only started experiencing it after migration).

**Issue 1:** When visiting a category page in the CMS, the category sidebars appear but the actual category form is blank.

**Issue 2:** The product columns in the CMS are offset by 1 - so SKU = Attribute Set, Attribute Set = Type etc etc

[image]

**Issue 3:** Issues on the frontend

- The minicart is blank when I click to open it
- The checkout doesn't load all of its assets

I've obviously cleared cache, redeployed all the assets. Even ran a lengthy set of commands to do that (as per [the magento forum](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/blank-page-magento-2/td-p/111865))

All signs seem to point to a knockout.js issue, but I can't seem to get any further than that.

As for error logs, I *was* getting an error like

> main.CRITICAL: Cannot gather stats!

But since refreshing the assets, that doesn't seem to occur anymore.

If anyone can help, I would be most grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried the following command,

```
sudo php bin/magento indexer:reset
sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Sometimes, it may work out! Recently I faced this kind of issue in the catalog page. After reindexing it works.

Comment: You don't need to use sudo